# Google Maps Infobox positioning

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using Google Maps with the `Array` below:

```
drivers = [{
    desc: 'teddy johnson | GPS: on <br> tow - light duty wheel lift <br> ETA: 15min ',
    lat: 42.366285,
    long: -71.135091,
    icon: {
        url: '../img/map-icon/RCWeb6_8MAP_IMG_InRoute (1).png',
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 24)
    },
    labelset: [-100, 50]
},
...
...
];}

... 
...
```

with `Infobox` options:

```
var myOptions = {
    content: boxa,
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 0,
    //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, 50),
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(drivers[i].labelset[0],
                                          drivers[i].labelset[1]),
    closeBoxURL: "",
    zIndex: null,
    isHidden: false,
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: false
};
```

I can control `Infobox` positions by using `pixelOffset` like this:

```
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, 50),
```

but when I am getting `(-100, 50)` value from the `Array` like this:

```
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(drivers[i].labelset[0],
                                       drivers[i].labelset[1])
```

it's not working?

Please help me on this?

Comment: please define "it's not working", what do you expect, what is the result, are there errors?

Comment: Sorry for my english, actually its not working when am getting pixelOffset from Array, but when am using like this "pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100, 50)", its working, but am actually looking to get pixelOffset from Array, please help on this,

Comment: it's hard to answer without seeing the context(e.g. what is `i`). More complete code or a link to that page would be helpful

Comment: Actually, name of the Array is drivers and "i" is the index of it and am running this in "for" loop by getting array length, am using multiple custom icons with their infobox, looking to control the position of individual infobox by using this pixelOffset values, so getting those values from Array, please let me know if its not clear??

Comment: I can imagine what you are trying to do, but to solve the error it's not enough to get a description of what you are doing